# Web server on windows 10 (IIS) accessible through localhost and 127.0.0.1 but not through computer name or IP Address

Tags: windows, iis, web, routes, localhost

I recently installed Metasploit on my windows 10 PC. It changed a lot of configurations I think.
Now even after uninstalling it I still have that issue.

I'm connected to a wireless network which gives me (192.168.1.100), usually when I type this address it takes me to the same site as (localhost) or (127.0.0.1) but now it doesn't.

Note that I'm trying to access that IP from the same PC not externally.

And ping 192.168.1.100 works, but ping 192.168.1.100:80 does not work.
And I'm pretty sure I've tried all the possible configurations for the IIS binding.

Comment: check network firewall

Comment: I've checked the firewall. And even disabled it. Still no luck

Comment: What do you mean by this? "And ping 192.168.1.100 works, but ping 192.168.1.100:80 does not work"